# Abstracts in different languages on the same page

Tags: languages, abstract

How to place 3 abstracts (English, French and Arabic) on on the same page?

I tried to put them in a single page, but it does not work :

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[Bjornstrup]{fncychap}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}
\begin{document}
 \begin{abstract}
   %abstract in french
 \end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Abstract}
\begin{abstract}
   %abstract in english
 \end{abstract}
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{ملخص}
\begin{abstract}
   %abstract in arabic
 \end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Couldn't you just put the three abstracts in the same `abstract` environment, with a little space between them? It looks to me like the `abstract` environment is designed to start a new page each time, at least in the `report` class.

Comment: If you don't really need the `report` class, using the `article` class you'll have all of them in the same page.

Comment: the summary arab it does not work too! but the other, each is displayed on a page : 
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{ملخص}
\begin{abstract}
   %abstract in arabic
 \end{abstract}

Comment: @karlkoeller : yes i need the report class

Comment: Put all abstract environment inside a single minipage.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel This did actually do the trick for me... unlike the answers...

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you don't need the `titlepage` class option (used by default in `report`), the easiest solution is to use `notitlepage`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\selectlanguage{french} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in French
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{english} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in English
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{ngerman} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in German
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{english}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice that I used the `babel` package with three modules: `ngerman`, `french`, and `english` (since `english` is the last declared language, this is the main language for the document) and then used `\selectlanguage` to change to the corresponding option for each abstract.

In your actual code you won't need `ngerman` (I only used `ngerman` to simulate a third language since I don't have the Arabic font you are using), so load only the `french` and `english` modules.

As **egreg** has mentioned in a comment, instead of issuing `\selectlanguage` commands, one can enclose the abstracts in languages different from the main one in `otherlanguage` environments. This is cleaner, for it doesn't require to reset the language at the end:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[ngerman,french,english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{arabtex}

\begin{document}
\begin{otherlanguage}{french} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in French
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract in English
\end{abstract}

\begin{otherlanguage}{ngerman} 
\begin{abstract}
Abstract in German
\end{abstract}
\end{otherlanguage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of issuing `\selectlanguage` commands, enclose the abstracts in languages different from the main one in a `\begin{otherlanguage}{<language>}` command. This is cleaner, for it doesn't require to reset the language at the end.

Comment: @egreg I've added your suggestion to my answer. Thanks!

Comment: May I ask why this code doesn't work for me when I am using the document class amsbook?

Comment: What about creating two \chapter*{ABSTRACT} and \chapter*{ABSTRACT2} ?

Answer (score 1):

The Answer we all were looking for, are the following two lines of code:

```
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endabstract}{\endtitlepage}{}{}{}
```

They redefine the `abstract` environment from it's original form.

```
\patchcmd{\abstract}{\titlepage}{\thispagestyle{empty}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\endabstract}{\endtitlepage}{\clearpage}{}{}
```

As a result you are able to put several abstracts on one page.
This also works perfect on overleaf with the use of a titlepage.