# Résumé instead of Abstract in ociamthesis (Oxford)

Tags: babel, thesis, abstract

I am writing a thesis in LaTeX. I've chosen the Oxford template and I adapted it to the requirements of my university. The thesis is almost complete, I miss the abstract and the conclusion, but now I am experiencing a problem. I would need to write the abstract both in english and in french, but I did not manage to change abstract title into résumé.
I add the code (that is basically that of the template):

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,singlespacing,openright]{ociamthesis}
\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{underscore}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{notoccite}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[skip=3pt,font=scriptsize]{caption}
\usepackage[skip=2pt,font=scriptsize]{subcaption}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cleveref}
 \usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{imakeidx}                      % Indice analitico
\makeindex[intoc] 
\usepackage{titlesec}
\hypersetup{breaklinks=true}

\usepackage{minitoc}

\usepackage{paralist}
\urlstyle{same}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}

\geometry{%
  a4paper, body={150mm,220mm},
  left=25mm,top=30mm,
  headheight=7mm,
  headsep=14mm,
  marginparsep=4mm, marginparwidth=27mm
}

\usepackage{cdlr}

\titlespacing*{\section}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}
{0pt}{5.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{4.3ex plus .2ex}
 \begin{document}


%set the number of sectioning levels that get number and appear in the contents
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\university{ETABLISSEMENT}
\univlogo{logo-ETABLISSEMENT.png}
\doctoral{XXXXXXXXXX}
\researchunit{XXXXXXXXXX}
\specialisation{XXXXXXXXXX}
\jury{Civilit\'e  Pr\'enom {\sc Nom}     }{ Grade    }{ Etablissement   \qquad   \qquad  \qquad } {Statut Jury    }
\jury{Civilit\'e  Pr\'enom {\sc Nom}     }{ Grade    }{ Etablissement         }{ Statut Jury    }
\jury{Civilit\'e  Pr\'enom {\sc Nom}     }{ Grade    }{ Etablissement         }{ Statut Jury    }
\jury{Civilit\'e  Pr\'enom {\sc Nom}     }{ Grade    }{ Etablissement         }{ Statut Jury    }
\jury{Civilit\'e  Pr\'enom {\sc Nom}     }{ Grade    }{ Etablissement         }{ Statut Jury    }




\maketitle

\include{dedication}        % include a dedication.tex file
\include{acknowlegements}   % include an acknowledgements.tex file
\include{abstract}          % include the abstract
\begin{romanpages}          % start roman page numbering
\dominitoc
\tableofcontents            % generate and include a table of contents
\listoffigures
\listoftables        
\end{romanpages}
\include{chapter1}
\include{chapter2}
\include{chapter3}
\include{chapter4}
\include{chapter5}
\include{chapter6}
\include{conclusions}
\appendix
\include{appendix1}
\include{appendix2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliography}
%uncomment next line to change bibliography name to references
%\renewcommand{\bibname}{References}
\bibliography{refs}        %use a bibtex bibliography file refs.bib
%\bibliographystyle{plain}  %use the plain bibliography style
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\printindex 

\end{document}
```

and then, separately in "abstract" I tried the following :

```
\selectlanguage{frenchb} \addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Résumé}} 
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract} 
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract} 
\end{abstract}
```

It regognizes french, but the title continues to be "Abstract". I also tried  other classes (memoir, report...), but the number of problems increases... 
Please consider I am a very beginner with LaTeX.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please give a pointer to `ociamthesis.cls`?

Comment: try this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118218/abstracts-in-different-languages-on-the-same-page

Comment: It really doesn't make sense to use a template for a specific university if you are not attending the university.  You have to invest time to do stuff you wouldn't need to do with using a [minimal template](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume the document class is the one downloadable at:

https://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/members/it/faqs/latex/thesis-class

The problem is that the environment `abstract` is (re)defined by the class to be:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  Abstract}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
```

which means that it doesn't take care of `\abstractname`.

You can add the following lines in the preamble to overcome this:

```
\renewenvironment{abstract} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  \abstractname}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,singlespacing,openright]{ociamthesis}
\usepackage[frenchb, english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewenvironment{abstract} {\begin{alwayssingle} \thispagestyle{empty}
  \begin{center}
  \vspace*{1.5cm}
  {\Large \bfseries  \abstractname}
  \end{center}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{alwayssingle}}


\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{frenchb} 
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract}
\end{abstract}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Note that all the environments (like `acknowledgements`) defined by the class have this issue. Surely the class is not meant for languages other than English.

Also note that

```
\addto\captionsfrench{\renewcommand{\abstractname}{Résumé}}
```

is not more needed since it is the default for `frenchb`.