# How do I put two abstracts in different languages in the acmart latex template?

Tags: templates, abstract, acm, acmart

Recently I've started to use the acmart template to write a paper for a conference, but I need to write the abstract in two languages and apparently  the template don't allow to write two abstracts, but I'm not sure about that.

I need to do something like that:

[image: Two abstracts in different languages.]

I've already tried the following solution, but it didn't worked in the template:
[Abstracts in different languages on the same page](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118218/abstracts-in-different-languages-on-the-same-page/118255)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`acmart`](//ctan.org/pkg/acmart) stores the contents placed within the `abstract` environment as-is. Therefore, it's possible to place multiple abstracts within a single `abstract` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for this example

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
  \textbf{Abstract A}\par
  \lipsum*[1] % First abstract
  \par
  \medskip % Add a small space between the two abstracts
  \textbf{Abstract B}\par
  \lipsum*[2] % Second abstract
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

---

If you wish to add keywords, you can add them to the `abstract` environment using the same setup as would usually be the case for the journal:

[image]

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\usepackage{lipsum} % Just for this example

\title{A title}
\author{An author}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
  \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indentation
  \textbf{Abstract A}\par
  \lipsum*[1] % First abstract
  \par
  \medskip
  % Keywords associated with first abstract
  {\small Additional Key Words and Phrases: one, two, three, four, five, six\par}
  \medskip % Add a small space between the two abstracts
  \textbf{Abstract B}\par
  \lipsum*[2] % Second abstract
  \par
  \medskip
  % Keywords associated with second abstract
  {\small Keywords: seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve\par}
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\hypersetup{% Manually insert keywords you would use
  pdfkeywords = {one, two, three, four, five, six, seven, eight, nine, ten, eleven, twelve}
}

\end{document}
```

Since you're not specifying any `\keywords`, you can update the PDF properties (done automatically by the `\documentclass` when you use `\keywords`) using `\hypersetup{pdfkeywords = {...}}`.

[image]

The prefix for the keywords depends on the `\documentclass` options you pass to `acmart`. In the above case, I used `Additional Key Words and Phrases` for the first and `Keywords` for the second. Change this to suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, It helped a lot, I only had to make some changes in the code of the template, but your answer was the most part of the solution to my problem.