# Two abstracts on same page with 'report'

Tags: page-breaking, abstract, report

I'm struggling to make my German and English abstract appear on the same page in my report document. Currently they appear on two separate pages, no matter how big the abstracts get. Can anybody help me out? :)

The solution provided in [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/70815/placing-in-the-same-page-two-abstract-in-different-language) does not work, probably because I use a `report` instead of an `article`:

```
Command \abstract already defined. {\par\bigskip}
```

This solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118218/abstracts-in-different-languages-on-the-same-page) doesn't work because I need the `titlepage` environment.

**EDIT (SOLUTION):** Changing `\newenvironment{abstract}` to `\renewenvironment{abstract}` as suggested by Marijn did the job! Many thanks :) Also thank you for the suggestion on loading `german` as the last option to `babel` - I did that as well :)

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{report} 

% packages I use
\usepackage[german, english]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}
\input{../setup/hyphenations}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage[scaled=.95]{helvet}
\usepackage{courier}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,width=14.2cm,left=36mm,height=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\linespread{1.15}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.5em}
\setlength{\parindent}{0em}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract} 
German Abstract
\end{abstract}

\selectlanguage{english}
\begin{abstract} 
English Abstract
\end{abstract}
\selectlanguage{german}

% some chapters / table of contents ...
\end{document}
```

Comment: Or possibly https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/118218/abstracts-in-different-languages-on-the-same-page is a better duplicate (because it uses `report`).

Comment: Edited my original question :)

Comment: Ok, I'll see if I can find another solution then.

Comment: Please make sure the MWE does not depend on resources we do not have access to (for example are the three lines with `\input` needed`?

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have included them. Will probably remove them now.

Comment: Try `\renewenvironment{abstract}` instead of `\newenvironment{abstract}` in the first duplicate, as suggested in the comments there for `article`. I just tried it and that works also for `report`.

Comment: BTW: if german is suppose to be the main language, then load it as the last option to babel. You might also want to wrap the english abstract in the otherlanguage env with argument `english`

Comment: @Marijn what exactly in report is even making it change the page after the abstract? I don't really see it

Comment: @daleif I'm not really sure, but the original definition of `\abstract` in `report` starts with `\titlepage` which has `\newpage` inside, so that might have something to do with it (and there is a `\vfil` there too).

Comment: @Marijn that should only be if the title page option is active, which it is not here.

Comment: Changing \newenvironment{abstract} to \renewenvironment{abstract} as suggested by Marijn did the job! Many thanks :) Also thank you for the suggestion on loading german as the last option to babel - I did that as well :)

Comment: Pass the explicit `notitlepage` option to report, then it does not chage pages.

Comment: @Marijn ohh, titlepage option is always true in report, unless `notitlepage` is explicitly given

Comment: @daleif for `report` the `titlepage` option is active by default I think.

Comment: @Marijn please feel free to provide an answer to the question so I can accept that and appreciate your effort :)

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `german` and not `ngerman`? `german` uses "Alte Rechtschreibung", `ngerman` uses "Neue Rechtschreibung".

Comment: Changed it to ngerman now - thanks :)

Answer (score -1):

Changing `\newenvironment{abstract}` to `\renewenvironment{abstract}` as suggested by Marijn did the job! Many thanks :) Also thank you for the suggestion on loading `german` as the last option to `babel` - I did that as well :)

Comment: Probably better to ask Marijn to provide an answer and then accept that.

Comment: I'd appreciate that :) Just wanted to provide one for now if someone stumbles across this thread.

Comment: Hm, I think it would be best to close as duplicate and not have an answer here at all - the `\renewenvironment` modification is also mentioned by egreg as a comment to his answer to the duplicate.